# Error npm install

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

Just downloaded project from https://github.com/angular/quickstart and run npm install command . I got the following. Please help.

```
$ npm install
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "ins
tall"
npm ERR! node v6.3.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo

npm ERR! getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:80  
npm ERR!  
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:  
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>



npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:  
npm ERR!     D:\quickstart\quickstart\npm-debug.log
```

Following https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html

PFB npm-debug.log

```
218 info attempt registry request try #3 at 3:28:48 PM
219 http request GET http://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcompiler
220 info attempt registry request try #3 at 3:28:48 PM
221 http request GET http://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcore
222 info attempt registry request try #3 at 3:28:48 PM
223 http request GET http://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fforms
224 silly fetchPackageMetaData Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:80
224 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1012:11)
224 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at errnoException (dns.js:33:15)
224 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:79:26)
224 silly fetchPackageMetaData  error for @angular/forms@~2.4.0 { Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:80
224 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1012:11)
224 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at errnoException (dns.js:33:15)
224 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:79:26)
224 silly fetchPackageMetaData   code: 'EAI_AGAIN',
224 silly fetchPackageMetaData   errno: 'EAI_AGAIN',
224 silly fetchPackageMetaData   syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
224 silly fetchPackageMetaData   hostname: 'registry.npmjs.org',
224 silly fetchPackageMetaData   host: 'registry.npmjs.org',
224 silly fetchPackageMetaData   port: 80 }
225 silly fetchPackageMetaData Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:80
225 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1012:11)
225 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at errnoException (dns.js:33:15)
225 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:79:26)
225 silly fetchPackageMetaData  error for @angular/compiler@~2.4.0 { Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:80
225 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1012:11)
225 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at errnoException (dns.js:33:15)
225 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:79:26)
225 silly fetchPackageMetaData   code: 'EAI_AGAIN',
225 silly fetchPackageMetaData   errno: 'EAI_AGAIN',
225 silly fetchPackageMetaData   syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
225 silly fetchPackageMetaData   hostname: 'registry.npmjs.org',
225 silly fetchPackageMetaData   host: 'registry.npmjs.org',
225 silly fetchPackageMetaData   port: 80 }
226 silly fetchPackageMetaData Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:80
226 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1012:11)
226 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at errnoException (dns.js:33:15)
226 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:79:26)
226 silly fetchPackageMetaData  error for @angular/core@~2.4.0 { Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:80
226 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1012:11)
226 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at errnoException (dns.js:33:15)
226 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:79:26)
226 silly fetchPackageMetaData   code: 'EAI_AGAIN',
226 silly fetchPackageMetaData   errno: 'EAI_AGAIN',
226 silly fetchPackageMetaData   syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
226 silly fetchPackageMetaData   hostname: 'registry.npmjs.org',
226 silly fetchPackageMetaData   host: 'registry.npmjs.org',
226 silly fetchPackageMetaData   port: 80 }
227 info attempt registry request try #3 at 3:28:58 PM
228 http request GET http://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2frouter
229 info attempt registry request try #3 at 3:28:58 PM
230 http request GET http://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcommon
231 info attempt registry request try #3 at 3:28:58 PM
232 http request GET http://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fhttp
233 info attempt registry request try #3 at 3:28:58 PM
234 http request GET http://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fplatform-browser-dynamic
235 info attempt registry request try #3 at 3:29:08 PM
236 http request GET http://registry.npmjs.org/systemjs
237 info attempt registry request try #3 at 3:29:08 PM
238 http request GET http://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fplatform-browser
239 info attempt registry request try #3 at 3:29:08 PM
240 http request GET http://registry.npmjs.org/core-js
241 info attempt registry request try #3 at 3:29:08 PM
242 http request GET http://registry.npmjs.org/rxjs
243 silly fetchPackageMetaData Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:80
243 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1012:11)
243 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at errnoException (dns.js:33:15)
243 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:79:26)
243 silly fetchPackageMetaData  error for @angular/http@~2.4.0 { Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:80
243 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1012:11)
243 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at errnoException (dns.js:33:15)
243 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:79:26)
243 silly fetchPackageMetaData   code: 'EAI_AGAIN',
243 silly fetchPackageMetaData   errno: 'EAI_AGAIN',
243 silly fetchPackageMetaData   syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
243 silly fetchPackageMetaData   hostname: 'registry.npmjs.org',
243 silly fetchPackageMetaData   host: 'registry.npmjs.org',
243 silly fetchPackageMetaData   port: 80 }
244 silly fetchPackageMetaData Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:80
244 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1012:11)
244 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at errnoException (dns.js:33:15)
244 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:79:26)
244 silly fetchPackageMetaData  error for @angular/common@~2.4.0 { Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:80
244 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1012:11)
244 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at errnoException (dns.js:33:15)
244 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:79:26)
244 silly fetchPackageMetaData   code: 'EAI_AGAIN',
244 silly fetchPackageMetaData   errno: 'EAI_AGAIN',
244 silly fetchPackageMetaData   syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
244 silly fetchPackageMetaData   hostname: 'registry.npmjs.org',
244 silly fetchPackageMetaData   host: 'registry.npmjs.org',
244 silly fetchPackageMetaData   port: 80 }
245 silly fetchPackageMetaData Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:80
245 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1012:11)
245 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at errnoException (dns.js:33:15)
245 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:79:26)
245 silly fetchPackageMetaData  error for @angular/router@~3.4.0 { Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:80
245 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1012:11)
245 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at errnoException (dns.js:33:15)
245 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:79:26)
245 silly fetchPackageMetaData   code: 'EAI_AGAIN',
245 silly fetchPackageMetaData   errno: 'EAI_AGAIN',
245 silly fetchPackageMetaData   syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
245 silly fetchPackageMetaData   hostname: 'registry.npmjs.org',
245 silly fetchPackageMetaData   host: 'registry.npmjs.org',
245 silly fetchPackageMetaData   port: 80 }
246 silly fetchPackageMetaData Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:80
246 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1012:11)
246 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at errnoException (dns.js:33:15)
246 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:79:26)
246 silly fetchPackageMetaData  error for @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@~2.4.0 { Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:80
246 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1012:11)
246 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at errnoException (dns.js:33:15)
246 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:79:26)
246 silly fetchPackageMetaData   code: 'EAI_AGAIN',
246 silly fetchPackageMetaData   errno: 'EAI_AGAIN',
246 silly fetchPackageMetaData   syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
246 silly fetchPackageMetaData   hostname: 'registry.npmjs.org',
246 silly fetchPackageMetaData   host: 'registry.npmjs.org',
246 silly fetchPackageMetaData   port: 80 }
247 silly fetchPackageMetaData Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:80
247 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1012:11)
247 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at errnoException (dns.js:33:15)
247 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:79:26)
247 silly fetchPackageMetaData  error for systemjs@0.19.40 { Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:80
247 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1012:11)
247 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at errnoException (dns.js:33:15)
247 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:79:26)
247 silly fetchPackageMetaData   code: 'EAI_AGAIN',
247 silly fetchPackageMetaData   errno: 'EAI_AGAIN',
247 silly fetchPackageMetaData   syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
247 silly fetchPackageMetaData   hostname: 'registry.npmjs.org',
247 silly fetchPackageMetaData   host: 'registry.npmjs.org',
247 silly fetchPackageMetaData   port: 80 }
248 silly fetchPackageMetaData Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:80
248 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1012:11)
248 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at errnoException (dns.js:33:15)
248 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:79:26)
248 silly fetchPackageMetaData  error for core-js@^2.4.1 { Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:80
248 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1012:11)
248 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at errnoException (dns.js:33:15)
248 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:79:26)
248 silly fetchPackageMetaData   code: 'EAI_AGAIN',
248 silly fetchPackageMetaData   errno: 'EAI_AGAIN',
248 silly fetchPackageMetaData   syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
248 silly fetchPackageMetaData   hostname: 'registry.npmjs.org',
248 silly fetchPackageMetaData   host: 'registry.npmjs.org',
248 silly fetchPackageMetaData   port: 80 }
249 silly fetchPackageMetaData Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:80
249 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1012:11)
249 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at errnoException (dns.js:33:15)
249 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:79:26)
249 silly fetchPackageMetaData  error for rxjs@5.0.1 { Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:80
249 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1012:11)
249 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at errnoException (dns.js:33:15)
249 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:79:26)
249 silly fetchPackageMetaData   code: 'EAI_AGAIN',
249 silly fetchPackageMetaData   errno: 'EAI_AGAIN',
249 silly fetchPackageMetaData   syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
249 silly fetchPackageMetaData   hostname: 'registry.npmjs.org',
249 silly fetchPackageMetaData   host: 'registry.npmjs.org',
249 silly fetchPackageMetaData   port: 80 }
250 silly fetchPackageMetaData Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:80
250 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1012:11)
250 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at errnoException (dns.js:33:15)
250 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:79:26)
250 silly fetchPackageMetaData  error for @angular/platform-browser@~2.4.0 { Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:80
250 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1012:11)
250 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at errnoException (dns.js:33:15)
250 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:79:26)
250 silly fetchPackageMetaData   code: 'EAI_AGAIN',
250 silly fetchPackageMetaData   errno: 'EAI_AGAIN',
250 silly fetchPackageMetaData   syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
250 silly fetchPackageMetaData   hostname: 'registry.npmjs.org',
250 silly fetchPackageMetaData   host: 'registry.npmjs.org',
250 silly fetchPackageMetaData   port: 80 }
251 info attempt registry request try #3 at 3:29:19 PM
252 http request GET http://registry.npmjs.org/angular-in-memory-web-api
253 info attempt registry request try #3 at 3:29:19 PM
254 http request GET http://registry.npmjs.org/zone.js
255 silly fetchPackageMetaData Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:80
255 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1012:11)
255 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at errnoException (dns.js:33:15)
255 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:79:26)
255 silly fetchPackageMetaData  error for zone.js@^0.7.4 { Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:80
255 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1012:11)
255 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at errnoException (dns.js:33:15)
255 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:79:26)
255 silly fetchPackageMetaData   code: 'EAI_AGAIN',
255 silly fetchPackageMetaData   errno: 'EAI_AGAIN',
255 silly fetchPackageMetaData   syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
255 silly fetchPackageMetaData   hostname: 'registry.npmjs.org',
255 silly fetchPackageMetaData   host: 'registry.npmjs.org',
255 silly fetchPackageMetaData   port: 80 }
256 silly fetchPackageMetaData Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:80
256 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1012:11)
256 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at errnoException (dns.js:33:15)
256 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:79:26)
256 silly fetchPackageMetaData  error for angular-in-memory-web-api@~0.2.4 { Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:80
256 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1012:11)
256 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at errnoException (dns.js:33:15)
256 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:79:26)
256 silly fetchPackageMetaData   code: 'EAI_AGAIN',
256 silly fetchPackageMetaData   errno: 'EAI_AGAIN',
256 silly fetchPackageMetaData   syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
256 silly fetchPackageMetaData   hostname: 'registry.npmjs.org',
256 silly fetchPackageMetaData   host: 'registry.npmjs.org',
256 silly fetchPackageMetaData   port: 80 }
257 silly rollbackFailedOptional Starting
258 silly rollbackFailedOptional Finishing
259 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Starting
260 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Finishing
261 silly install printInstalled
262 verbose stack Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:80
262 verbose stack     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1012:11)
262 verbose stack     at errnoException (dns.js:33:15)
262 verbose stack     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:79:26)
263 verbose cwd D:\quickstart\quickstart
264 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
265 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
266 error node v6.3.1
267 error npm  v3.10.3
268 error code EAI_AGAIN
269 error errno EAI_AGAIN
270 error syscall getaddrinfo
271 error getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:80
272 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
272 error     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
273 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: You should include `npm-debug.log` in your question.

Comment: @JoeClay can u plz chk now. removed starting of npm-debug.log. because stackoverflow not supporting more than 30000 chars

Comment: are you using some sort of proxy? https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7348

Comment: I second @suraj's question - the `EAI_AGAIN` error indicates that DNS resolution is failing when NPM tries to connect, which sounds very much like a proxy/internet connectivity issue.